# Skip test unit in Ruby on Rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I am learning it thru http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#top this tutorial.

One command given in this tutorial is not working for me

```
rails new sample_app --skip-test-unit
```

Error text is

> Invalid option --skip-test-unit

Any idea why it is not working and how I can solve it?

Comment: What do you see when you run `rails -v` ?

Comment: ok, got it. Version is some 2.3, somehow my latest rails version 3.2.9 is missing.

Comment: Thought so; most likely the `--skip-test-unit` option wasn't in `rails 2.3`. Make sure you have rvm set up correctly, and are using the correct version of ruby & rails. Also, `rails new -h` will show all the available options on both versions.

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
rails new sample_app -T
```

Answer (score 0):

For completion's sake, transferring the answer here from the comments:

`rails -v` showed that the app was running `rails 2.3` version instead of the expected `rails 3.2.9` version.  `--skip-test-unit` is not a valid option in `rails 2.3` version

Answer (score 0):

just create your app with `rails new my_app`, and then add the codes below.

```rb
# config/application.rb
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework nil
end
```

and then, when you using `rails g controller home`, it will not generate test unit automaticity.